# How to find the determinant of a transformation matrix given two sets of 3 vertices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, determinant

[image]

I'm not sure how to use this information. It also isn't clear, I'm assuming the points are in their respective orders. If so, then I know:

$
\begin{bmatrix} 
1\\
0\\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
$
multiplied by unknown transformation matrix = $
\begin{bmatrix} 
0\\
6\\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
$

How would I know what it was though? Apparently the answer is that the determinant of matrix $A$ is $15$, but I'm not exactly sure how they got that answer.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. You don't need to find $A$ to know its determinant. All you have to know is that the determinant is the factor by which $A$ scales all areas.

Comment: hmm intersting. so if I calculate the areas of the triangles, would that help me? what would I do with those?

Comment: Yes, Calculating the areas would help. Their ratio would be the absolute value of the determinant.

Answer (score 1):

The determinant is the ratio of the areas. Just divide the area of the transformed triangle by the area of the original one. $(15/2)/(1/2)=15$.

Comment: Do you mean 15?

Comment: Sure I did. Just a typo..

Comment: thanks! this makes sense now